# C# create yyyy-mm-dd dir easy

Tags: c#

How should i do to create yyyy/mm/dd directory easy?
mysite.com/blog**/2009/01/01/**hello-world.aspx!

Comment: /** etc. are invalid. Not allowed for directory names. Hope you meant innder folders.

Comment: Do you actually want to create physical directories on the filesystem, or do you simply want to use that URL pattern for accessing the site through your web server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
              "mysite.com/blog**/{0:yyyy/MM/dd}/**hello-world.aspx", 
              DateTime.Now)
```

Will get you the date. You can add more parameters to it to get it just right.

Comment: I don't belive that you need the invariant culture (not that it hurts) here Jeff as you are declaring the format yourself rather than calling a default format type.

Comment: In the Turkish culture "tr-TR", the framework will replace "/" with ".". Try it.

Comment: I had forgotten this and that I had to escape the seperator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Uri class to combine the url together and use / to escape the \ character to be explicit rather than the cultural date seperator.

```
Uri oSiteBase = new Uri("http://mysite.com/blog");
Uri oSiteDay = new Uri(oSiteBase, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy\/MM\/dd"));
```

Comment: Be aware that this solution has Turkey Test issues: http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: I don't think so, I'm explicitly calling the format to output the year, month and day in my order with my seperator.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR")) == "2008.05.22" != "2008/05/22"

Comment: @Jeff - I had forgotten that / refers to the default date seperator and that you need to escape it with a \ to force it. The code is changed to show this.

Comment: Alternatively you can say DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) (this is what Format is doing internally)

Comment: @Jeff - Agreed, nothing wrong with either case but I prefer DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy\/MM\/dd"), no culture knowledge here required.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Jeff's answer:

```
String foo = "mysite.com/blog/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy\/mm\/dd") + "/hello-world.aspx";
```

Comment: Be aware that this solution has Turkey Test issues: http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: Why remove the string.Format? I can understand removing the invariant culture, but not the format.

Comment: @Stevo3000: Well, I removed the string.format because the data formatting itself is being handled by DateTimeNow.ToString.  However, it wasn't necessary.  It's just a variation.

Comment: @Jeff: What issues? I'm explicitely setting the formatting to yyyy/mm/dd .

Comment: Set your culture to Turkish "tr-TR" or simulate it by passing CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR") and see that "/" goes to "."

Comment: @Moser: Oh, good to know.  I Escaped the \ as suggested by Stevo.